# DBA readonly account

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I had a schema in one oracle DB as ui_prod. I asked my DBA team guys to create exactly same schema like ui_prod but as read only and name it ui_prod_readonly. Usually I will use Oracle SQL developer to connect a DB and query directly with table name like below.

```
--Connect to ui_prod
select * from table
```

but why I requested to put owner name infront when query for readonly schema they created for me, as without putting it, I get error table not exist.

```
--Connect to ui_prod_readonly
select * from ui_prod.table
```

I have project files which hardcode the sql query with only table names and adding owner name in front will cause many changes and effort. Can anyone explain me on this? or provide me any document/link to read. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should look into synonyms, apparently the user you are connecting to the database as is not the owner of the objects. So to view the object you have to prepend the names with the schema name (the owner of the object themselves).

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/synonyms.php

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  SYNONYM ui_prod_readonly.synonym_name
  FOR ui_prod.object_name
```

It seems to me that your dbas have not created another set of tables but just granted the existing tables to the user ui_prod_readonly.

Answer (score 1):

When you log in to Oracle, the current schema is the name of the user you used to log in. So if you log in with `ui_prod_readonly` Oracle checks *that* schema for the table if you do not qualify it with the owner (=schema).

If you want to change the current schema so that you don't need to fully qualify the tables, you can do that with `ALTER SESSION`

```
alter session set current_schema = ui_prod;
```

Once you have done that, you don't need to fully qualify the table with the owner (=schema).

Answer (score 1):

if you need a user to read the data only 
its simple to create new user and grant it only select privilege

you can create user and grant select privilege using

```
CREATE USER [user] IDENTIFIED BY [your_password];
grant select on table to [user]
```